# What does the dot after dollar sign mean in jQuery when declaring variables?

Tags: jquery

I see variables declared as:

```
$.root = $("body");
```

and

```
$root = $("body");
```

What is the difference between the two?

Comment: basically: `var a = 1;` and `var x = {}; x.a = 1;`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Functions in JavaScript are objects. And like most objects in JavaScript, you can arbitrarily add properties to them. The `$` function is just that, a function. So if you want to pop a property onto it and reference a jQuery collection, or reference, you can.

By adding the collection as a property on the `$` function, it is one less variable in the current scope. You can examine the keys of the jQuery function before and after if you'd like to see how it affects the function's topography and (enumerable) property list:

```js
Object.keys($);
// ["fn", "extend", "expando"..."parseHTML", "offset", "noConflict"]

$.root = $("body");
// [<body>]

Object.keys($);
// ["fn", "extend", "expando"..."parseHTML", "offset", "noConflict", "root"]
```

Comment: "... one less variable in the current scope ...".  Still not clear on why that is better, or when it is better and when it is not.

Comment: @CraigHicks By not having a `root` var in the scope, you have no chance of colliding it with any other `root` var you may introduce later. To be honest, I don't think there is any good reason to do what I'm suggesting above, especially since we now have `let`. I only showed it because the author asked.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - somehow I missed learning about "let" until your mentioned it! I was worried that once the secret got out about using "$." as a storage place it would get overrun with tourists - but now I don't have to worry,

Answer (score 12):

```
$.root = $("body");
```

This adds a property to the $ functor (often referred to as the jQuery object, as $ == jQuery)

```
$root = $("body");
```

This adds a property to the 'global' scope, aka the *window* object in javascript.
You can also refer the latter as

```
window.$root
```

Answer (score 9):

The first one is creating a property called root in jquery and setting its value. The second one is only defining that the variable with name $root has the value on the right.